# Increase TCP disconnection time

Tags: c#, tcp, raspberry-pi, tcpclient

I know TCP won't break an established TCP connection during a period of time. But is it possible to increase this time?

I am developing a client-server application used to stream continuous data from one server to the client application using C#. I want to keep collecting data if the cable connection reconnected within one minute.

Comment: My client application can read full data when I disconnect and connect the ethernet cable within 5 seconds... But the connection drops when I disconnect the cable more than 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

There are three timeouts that you can use in the tcp client:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netcore-3.1#properties

- Connect timeout. The time it takes to establish the connection
- Receive timeout. The timeout on the receiving side once the reading is initiated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient_ReceiveTimeout
- Send timeout. The timeout on the sender side once the sending is initiated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.sendtimeout?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Sockets_TcpClient_SendTimeout

Those are the out of the box settings you can use. If you didn't mean one of these, please clarify in your question.

Comment: Thanks  for your reply... My client application can read full data when I disconnect and connect the ethernet cable within 5 seconds... But the connection drops when I disconnect the cable more than 30 seconds...